# Iterative Merge Sort seems incorrect - produces valid output

Tags: java, sorting, mergesort

I understand that iterative `merge sort` can be found online, however this implementation that I have created seems vastly different than the examples I have seen online.

Here is what I have. I implemented this iteratively, but think that it isn't correct as this is not exactly what the `recursive` implementation follows.

The recursive implementation `splits/sorts` one half and then the other and then merges. This implementation splits/sorts the entire list, and then merges them one by one with the `stack`.

My question is, is this a correct iterative implementation? 

I'm thinking I should be using a `queue` instead of a `stack`.

```
public static List<Integer> iterativeMergeSort(List<Integer> nums){

    Stack<List<Integer>> stack = new Stack<List<Integer>>();

    for (int num : nums) {
        stack.push(new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(num)));
    }

    while (stack.size() > 1) {
        List<Integer> a = stack.pop();
        List<Integer> b = stack.pop();
        stack.push(merge(a,b));
    }

    return stack.pop();
}

public static List<Integer> merge(List<Integer> a, List<Integer> b) {

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    List<Integer> merged = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    while (i < a.size() && j < b.size()) {

        if (a.get(i) == b.get(j)) {
            merged.add(a.get(i));
            merged.add(b.get(j));
            i++;
            j++;
        }
        else if (a.get(i) < b.get(j)) {
            merged.add(a.get(i));
            i++;
        }
        else { //a.get(i) > b.get(j)
            merged.add(b.get(j));
            j++;
        }
    }

    while (i < a.size()) {
        merged.add(a.get(i));
        i++;
    }

    while (j < b.size()) {
        merged.add(b.get(j));
        j++;
    }

    return merged;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This implementation feels wrong to me.  This is more of an insertion_sort (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort).  The idea with merge sort is that you split the data into 2 near even groups, but this implementation isn't doing that.  Your 'a' is basically a list of previously sorted elements and 'b' is the next element to add.

Comment: if it were to be a queue, then we would be merging lists of similar size each time, right? this would be merge sort?

Comment: I guess depending how you implement it it could work yes.

Comment: It does seem like queue would be easier to work with.  you can merge the first 2 elements than add the result to the queue and keep going until it's got 1 element left.

Answer (score 0):

Iterative merge sort is normally bottom up. Rather than using repeated recursion to split up an array, a bottom up merge sort skips that step and treats an array of n elements as n runs of size 1, and immediately starts merging runs. Top down merge sort is only splitting up sub-runs until it produces two sub-runs of size 1 before any merging is performed, and is slightly slower, which is why most libraries use some variation of bottom up merge sort. Wiki article includes psuedo code for bottom up merge sort:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Bottom-up_implementation

The copy back steps can be avoided by swapping pointers or references instead of copying.